# WP Woo <noscript> in header Need removal

Tags: woocommerce, noscript

I am using WP Woo commerce with non woo commerce theme.

When I activate woo commerce plugin this line is inserted into my header:

```
<noscript>.woocommerce-product-gallery{ opacity: 1 !important; }</noscript>
```

Could someone help me remove this from header with woocommerce activated?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `<noscript>` element with:

```
function myplugin_remove_noscript()
{
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'wc_gallery_noscript' );
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'myplugin_remove_noscript', 9 );
```

(WP Woocommerce inserted this element by using `add_action`)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind I just changed theme to woo commerce. It happened after their last update, probably will only get worse with future updates. Better to bite the bullet now and change.

close thread